# Tab CSS not staying highlighted on active tab upon loading page or clicking somewhere else

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tabs

The nav tab is created using Bootstrap 4. When the page loads, it automatically loads the home tab (desired), but the home tab is not highlighted. Clicking on the tab (or any of the other tabs) will highlight the tab correctly, but the second issue is that upon clicking the mouse anywhere else, the highlight disappears.

I would like to solve two issues:

1. Have the home page already be highlighted as active when loading the page in.
2. When clicking the cursor anywhere on the page, still have the active tab stay highlighted.

[image: The page loads Home first but the Home tab is not highlighted]

```css
/* And here is the CSS */

nav>.nav.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #005440;
  border-radius: 0;
}

nav>div a.nav-item.nav-link,
nav>div a.nav-item.nav-link.active {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #005440;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.tab-content {
  background: rgb(254, 254, 254);
  line-height: 25px;
  border-top: 5px solid #006950;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #006950;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 30px 25%;
}

nav>div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover,
nav>div a.nav-item.nav-link:focus {
  border: none;
  background: #006950;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: background 0.20s linear;
}
```

```html
<!-- Here is the HTML body -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 ">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
          Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt
          irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis
          reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
          Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt
          irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis
          reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
          Et et consectetur ipsum labore excepteur est proident excepteur ad velit occaecat qui minim occaecat veniam. Fugiat veniam incididunt anim aliqua enim pariatur veniam sunt est aute sit dolor anim. Velit non irure adipisicing aliqua ullamco irure incididunt
          irure non esse consectetur nostrud minim non minim occaecat. Amet duis do nisi duis veniam non est eiusmod tempor incididunt tempor dolor ipsum in qui sit. Exercitation mollit sit culpa nisi culpa non adipisicing reprehenderit do dolore. Duis
          reprehenderit occaecat anim ullamco ad duis occaecat ex.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried debugging it and I know the issue is somewhere with

```
nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover,
nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link:focus
```

-in the CSS but I just can't figure out what.

If you guys see anything that can be improved let know, still figuring out HTML and CSS. Thank you!

Comment: The issue is not with ```hover``` or ```focus``` pseudo-classes but you should look at the code where you are styling the class ```active```. You will need to use some javascript to change(add/remove) the active class of nav when clicked .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two selectors:

```
nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover,
nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link:focus
```

are only applying their styles when the nav item is hovered or focused, which is the behaviour you're experiencing - when you click away you are no longer hovering/focusing the element.

You want to also apply that style to the **active** class that is applied to the home tab.

Change your css to this:

```
nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover,
nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link:focus,
nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link.active
{
  border: none;
    background: #006950;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:0;
    transition:background 0.20s linear;
}
```

This will apply the style to whatever nav item is active as well as nav items that you hover or focus.

Comment: Just to make sure, I don't need to delete the previous nav > div a.nav-item.nav-link.active from a previous segment? I have duplicates of these selectors now. Will it cause conflicts? Just a precaution; thanks for your solution! It works great.

Comment: Duplicate selectors are technically fine. CSS stands for "cascading style sheets" - the cascading referring to later styles overriding earlier styles. So as long as the styles you want are appearing later in the code then they will override earlier styles. If you inspect the element in dev-tools you'll see that both sets of styles are being applied with the later set taking precedence.